# Zend FlashMessenger problems

Tags: zend-framework-mvc

I am new to Zend framework and I have a problem.
I created a controller abstract class which implements the functions like:

```
protected function AddError($message) {
    $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
    $flashMessenger->setNamespace('Errors');
    $flashMessenger->addMessage($message);
    $this->view->Errors = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
}

protected function activateErrors()
{
    $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
    $flashMessenger->setNamespace('Errors');
    $this->view->Errors = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
}
```

So for each controller I am able to use 
$this->AddError($error);
And then I render $error in layout.
So I want not to deal with flashMesenger in every controller.

but I have to execute the activateErrors when each action is executed.

for example

I have an controller test

class TestController extends MyController {

```
public function indexAction() {

    $this->AddError("Error 1");
    $this->AddError("Error 2");
    $this->activateErrors();
}


public function index1Action() {

    $this->AddError("Esdsd 1");
    $this->AddError("sddsd 2");
    $this->activateErrors();
}
```

}

Is there a way that I could execute this activateErrors in each action for every controller at the end of action without duplicating the code.

I mean I do not want to include this code at every action. Maybe there is a way to include it in my abstract class MyController.

Anybody any Idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [postDispatch hook](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.prepostdispatch), in your parent `MyController` ?

Quoting that page :

> `Zend_Controller_Action` specifies two
>   methods that may be called to bookend
>   a requested action, `preDispatch()`  and
>   `postDispatch()`. 
> These can be useful in
>   a variety of ways: verifying
>   authentication and ACL's prior to
>   running an action *(by calling
>   `_forward()` in `preDispatch()`, the action will be skipped)*, for instance,
>   or placing generated content in a
>   sitewide template *(`postDispatch()`)*.

Maybe this might do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually contributed [an enhancement to FlashMessenger](https://github.com/ToastedSnow/Zend-Framework-Rails-Messenger) which provides a lot of the functionality you're looking for.